# How to get Datasource name in EJB jar dynamically based on client application

Tags: java, ejb, datasource, jndi

I have a reusable EBJ jar which is used in a middleware rest application and in a JavaSE batch application. Unfortunately Datasource JNDIs are created differently in both JSE application and rest application. I'm injecting Datasource resource object as below in Data layer class of EJB with JNDI look up name. Now I have to inject two datasources pointing to same DB and schema which I want to avoid. That means I want to inject Datasource object with dynamic look up string.

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY)
public class MyDlService   {

    @Resource(lookup = jdbc/db)
    private DataSource dataSource;
}
```

What is the correct way to get JNDI datasource name in my EJB dynamically, that is based on the client application (here my JSE batch and middleware Rest application) ?

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What creates and manages EJBs in your JavaSE application?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19830-01/819-4725/abmdz/index.html 
did you try this or you need to inject it throught Resource?